# How to hijack a button's click event with my own ajax get function? Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, javascript, jquery

I am tying to add a new button to an existing admin page. 
I want to call an ajax get() function on this button click. 
I created a main.js script file which I see is loading on this page since when I do a console.log the code gets here. 
Though there's another script file that is "hijacking" this button's click. 
Instead of my ajax function being triggered from main.js, another JS function is being triggered from a require_js.phtml file.

The code in require_js.phtml file:

```
<?php
?>
<script>
var BASE_URL = '<?=/* @noEscape */$block->getUrl('*')?>';
//var FORM_KEY = '<?=/* @noEscape */$block->getFormKey()?>';
var require = {
    "baseUrl": "<?=/* @noEscape */$block->getViewFileUrl('/')?>"
};
</script>
```

This is the JS ajax function I am trying to trigger from main.js but is getting "hijacked". Though console.log("jivet click"); is being logged.

```
$("#jivet").click(function() {
    console.log("jivet click");
    $.get(
        "https://online.jivet.com/api/index.aspx?action=GetAllDIDs",
        function(data) {
            console.log("page content: " + data);
        }
    );
});
```

I see in the network tab in chrome that the ajax get call is being cancelled and the call from require_js.phtml is overtaking it. 
Screenshot below
https://gyazo.com/f2a47526c6eaacffec72a7f075ba74ce